# Android WebView Auto Facebook Login

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication, webview

Currently in my app, I have a WebView that loads a Facebook page. Naturally, the loaded Facebook page in my WebView does not have any user logged in to a Facebook account. By interacting with the WebView, the user can currently tap and enter their Facebook username and password in the top right of the web page where Facebook presents the Login button. Once the user has logged in to their account, any time after where my app implements a WebView the user remains logged in to Facebook.

My question is: Is there a way I can skip the initial task of having to interact with the WebView to authenticate a valid Facebook session with my app's WebView which stays logged in throughout the rest of my app's WebView usages? Preferably, I'd just like to pass the username and password as variables to the WebView and have the user logged in on the first Facebook page load of my WebView. If that's not possible, maybe there's a way to get a copy of what a logged in WebView session looks like (via Cookies or something else) and then just use that record for WebView instances on new app installs?

Answer (score 0):

If the user in logged into Facebook in their web browser and it's not an absolute requirement that you use a `WebView` specifically, you could use the [Custom Tabs feature of the AndroidX Browser library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/browser/customtabs/package-summary) See this [blog post](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) for some examples, though it uses an older version of the library.  This would use their existing Facebook session.

Comment: unfortunately i need to use a webview for this. Thanks for the idea though